# Java LinkedList - differences between retrieve operations

Tags: java, linked-list, duplicates, javadoc

Are there any differences between different methods in each of the following groups of element retrieve operations in `LinkedList`?

**Returning null + removing operations:** `poll()`, `pollFirst()`.

**Returning null + not removing operations:** `peek()`, `peekFirst()`.

**Throwing exception + removing operations:** `pop()`, `remove()`, `removeFirst()`.

**Throwing exception + not removing operations:** `element()`, `getFirst()`.

Similar duplications exists in insertion methods.

If there is no such difference, I would expect it to be mentioned in the javadoc of the methods (something like the good old "This is exactly like calling ..."). Is it only a sloppy documentation, or am I missing anything?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Isn't the javadoc clear. It says what each of those methods does quite clearly. What's the problem?

Comment: If there is any duplication, it's because `LinkedList` is implementing multiple base interfaces (`Deque`, `List`, `Queue`, etc.)

Comment: @JBNizet - The javadoc is clear, but the duplication is still there.
@OliCharlesworth - Most of the duplications are inside `Deque`, which implies I should have put the question about `Deque` itself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no difference between them, and it is listed in the documentation too, but you have to do some recursive searching to get there.

[`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implements two interfaces - [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) and [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html).  And `Deque` extends from `Queue`.

Now, `Deque` has defined the method - [`Deque#pollFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#pollFirst%28%29) and inherited the method - [`Queue#poll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#poll%28%29).

So, `LinkedList` has basically these two methods defined for the two interfaces it implements.

And about the similarity between those two methods, it is listed in documentation of [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) as:

> This interface extends the Queue interface. When a deque is used as a
>   queue, FIFO (First-In-First-Out) behavior results. Elements are added
>   at the end of the deque and removed from the beginning. The methods
>   inherited from the Queue interface are precisely equivalent to Deque
>   methods as indicated in the following table:

And there is a table listing the methods of `Queue` class and the equivalent `Deque` method. See [`Deque#poll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#poll%28%29), [`Deque#peek()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#peek%28%29) for e.g. They clearly list the equivalent method.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between them is version they were released with and the interfaces that LinkedList implements.

**Example based on `poll()` and `pollFirst()`:**

`LinkedList` was released along with **Java 1.2**.

**Since 1.5** LinkedList implements the Queue interface, which has

```
public E poll()
```

**Since 1.6** LinkedList implements the Deque interface, which has

```
public E pollFirst()
```

edit:
<strike>It is important to keep the older implementation due to a backward compatibility.</strike>

Comment: Thanks, that is probably right. The only exception is the pair removeFirst() and pop() where the javadoc does say "This method is equivalent to removeFirst()".

Comment: Backward compatibility is not the reason.  The reason is that `LinkedList` implements multiple interfaces.

Comment: @Elist. Note that the reason in the answer is not correct. Just FYK

Comment: @miller.bartek. It is not due to backward compatibility. It's just that `Deque` was added in Java 6, and was not there in `Java 5`. So, LinkedList didn't implemented `Deque`, and hence was not having that method. But, now, it implements both of those interfaces.

Comment: @miller. So those methods are not themselves a part of LinkedList, but are derived from the iterfaces it implements.

Comment: I agree. I striked out the wrong sentence. I still believe that the mentioned difference (versions) is correct.

Comment: @miller.bartek. Your answer still conveys that those methods are a part of LinkedList, and `pollFirst` was added to LinkedList in Java 6. This is not completely wrong, but is not completely right too.

Answer (score 0):

Your right it's bad documentation or something.

peek()
Retrieves, but does not remove, the head (first element) of this list.

peekFirst()
Retrieves, but does not remove, the first element of this list, or returns null if this list is empty.

This is what it says and I'm read here in my Java book that the head is the first item in a list.