# whats the difference between poll() and pop() for linkedlist in java?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I recently found there are two similar methods for linkedlist in java API, they all delete the first node and return it. I wrote the following codes to test and they did exactly same thing.Do they really work exactly same?

```
    test.add(1);
    test.add(2);
    test.add(3);
    System.out.println(test.pop());
    for(int i = 0; i < test.size();i++ ){
        System.out.print(test.get(i) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(test.poll());
    for(int i = 0; i < test.size();i++ ){
        System.out.print(test.get(i) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: The purpose of JavaDoc is not to ignore it: [#poll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#poll%28%29) / [#pop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#pop%28%29)

Comment: Refer this answer.Its pretty much clear your doubts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851367/java-linkedlist-differences-between-retrieve-operations

Answer (score 41):

Returning null + removing operations: `poll()` [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#poll())

Throwing exception + removing operations: `pop()`[docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#pop())

Answer (score 11):

They're functionally equivalent (save for how they handle the empty-list case), but you get both variants because `LinkedList` is an implementation of both a queue and a stack (namely [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#poll--) and [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#pop--)).

You can see their implementations in the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java):

```
public E poll() {
    final Node<E> f = first;
    return (f == null) ? null : unlinkFirst(f);
}

public E pop() {
    return removeFirst();
}

public E removeFirst() {
    final Node<E> f = first;
    if (f == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return unlinkFirst(f);
}
```

So `poll()` returns null if the list is empty, and `pop()` (and `removeFirst()`) raises a `NoSuchElementException`. This makes `pop()` a slightly nicer method to use, since you don't have to deal with nulls.

Comment: "pop() is slightly nicer", really? Handling null over handling runtime exceptions is much nicer IMO.

Comment: To each their own, but I think you'll find you're in the minority on this point. Nulls, and the subtle and unexpected behavior they cause, have been called a "[billion-dollar mistake](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained)". Exceptions offer clear failures, obvious stack traces, and generally make catching logic errors easier.